# how to include object into category or subcategory?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make that sort of relations:

```
└───SCOPE01
    ├───PROJECT01
    │   └───WORKER01
    └───WORKER02
```

Worker can be busy on some project or be free on some scope.
Have I chosen the right approach, and **how can I do otherwise**?

```
#models.py
from django.db import models


class Scope(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    scope = models.ForeignKey(
        Scope,
        related_name='projects',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class Worker(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    scope = models.ForeignKey(
        Scope,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

If that is correct, how to limit the simultaneous worker addition into both scope and project?

Comment: Maybe also add `null=True` in your `project FK` and `scope FK` in `worker` model because the way it is right now you will have to define both project and scope for each worker.

Comment: even if I add this, it will still be possible to specify both at once, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Worker can be busy on some project or be free on some scope. Have I chosen the right approach ?

Not enough specs to tell. Is this an exclusive "or" ? What does "free on some scope" mean ? What is a "scope" actually ? Can a worker change from "being free" on scope A to "being busy on a project" that belongs to scope B ? Can a worker be neither "busy on some project" NOR "free on some scope" ?

And those are only the first few qustions that come to mind... IOW: your "spec" is certainly clear for someone that knows the context, but *we* don't !-)

> If that is correct

Actually, not quite - at least `Worker.project` should be nullable so a worker can be "free on some scope" :

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    scope = models.ForeignKey(
        Scope,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

> how to limit the simultaneous worker addition into both scope and project?

if this means that a worker should be associated to either a scope XOR (exclusive or) a project, then you have to make both fields nullable:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    scope = models.ForeignKey(
        Scope,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Then you can 1/ add a couple methods to your Worker class to assign it to a project or scope (and nulling the other relationship at the same time):

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    scope = models.ForeignKey(
        Scope,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def assign_to_project(self, project, commit=True):
        self.project = project
        self.scope = None
        if commit:
            self.save()

   def assign_to_scope(self, scope, commit=True):
        self.scope = scope
        self.project = None
        if commit:
            self.save()
```

and then add some validation, either in the `save()` method (easy but not necessarily the best solution):

```
   def save(self, *args, **kw):
       if self.project and self.scope:
           raise SomeCustomException("cannot assign worker to both a scope and project at the same time")
       super(Worker, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

or [using model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) - but then you have to make sure the `full_clean` method (which invokes the `clean` method) is called (modelforms will do so automagically, but that's about all). But you can of course call `full_clean` yourself in the `save` method:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    scope = models.ForeignKey(
        Scope,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def assign_to_project(self, project, commit=True):
        self.project = project
        self.scope = None
        if commit:
            self.save()

   def assign_to_scope(self, scope, commit=True):
        self.scope = scope
        self.project = None
        if commit:
            self.save()


   def clean(self):
       if self.project and self.scope:
           raise ValidationError("cannot assign worker to both a scope and project at the same time")

   def save(self, *args, **kw):
       self.full_clean()
       super(Worker, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

EDIT: (about the `assign_to_scope()` and `assign_to_project()` methods)

> Does this mean that they will be called automatically, or can I call them explicitly when needed? I just cannot understand at what point will they be called? - they aren't called in your code

Sorry, this was obvious to me but no, there's no magic here, you must call those methods yourself where appropriate - one of the first obvious places being your modelforms and/or views and/or drf serializers (if you're using drf) etc. I didn't provide any example because I have no clue how you're going to use those models actually.

While we're at it, you probably want to mark those fields as "protected" (if you're new to python: prefix their names with a single leading underscore, which is the convention to say that an attribute shouldn't be directly accessed) and provide read-only public accessors, ie (nb: Q&D example code, may ontains typos or other bugs):

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    _project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    @property
    def project(self):
        return self._project

    _scope = models.ForeignKey(
        Scope,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='workers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    @property
    def scope(self):
        return self._scope

    def assign_to_project(self, project, commit=True):
        self._project = project
        self._scope = None
        if commit:
            self.save()

   def assign_to_scope(self, scope, commit=True):
        self._scope = scope
        self._project = None
        if commit:
            self.save()

   def clean(self):
       if self._project and self._scope:
           raise ValidationError("cannot assign worker to both a scope and project at the same time")


   # etc
```

Comment: My thanks for the detailed answer.
Could you please explain why am i needed assign_to_project and assign_to_scope methods? Is it needed to use beyond the admin? What means commit=True?

Comment: @gek you don't NEED those methods - they were intended as a way to make sure that assigning a worker to a project or a scope would also unset the other relationship. That's domain logic, and as such should be encapsulated in the model.

Comment: @gek: the use of the `commit` argument should be quite clear reading the code - usually you'll want to save your worker when assigning it to a scope or project (so the default is True), but sometimes you have other changes to apply at the same time and don't want to issue two or more db queries, so you can tell the method to not save right now. That's a very common pattern in Django projects - at least if you try to keep as much of the domain logic at the right place, ie in the models.

Comment: >That's domain logic, and as such should be encapsulated in the model.
Does this mean that they will be called automatically, or can I call them explicitly when needed? I just cannot understand at what point will they be called? - they aren't called in your code.